# Can't access Microsoft Graph users calendars 403

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I have seen other posts that are very similar, but I don't find a real answer.  Some say "it is coming", those are old.

I am authenticating with the Admin credentials to our O365 and trying to pull calendar information.  The Scope has Calendars.ReadWrite (which falls under App-Only and Delegate as far as scopes), but it always returns a 403.  ErrorAccessDenied, "Access is denied. Check credentials and try again"

The Graph doc for calendar views shows it can send in users/{id} in the request, and the id's came back when I listed all the users.  Of course if I use mine, it works.

If there really is an App-Only scope vs a Delegate scope for this same scope name, how do you specify that?

Is there something I have to specify in O365 for my admin user so it has rights?  I can delete or create any user with that account in O365, so it appears it should have what it needs.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

So, App-Only has a slightly different flow.

First, instead of authenticating the user at "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize", you authenticate them at "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/adminconsent".

Second, you pass in the same parameters minus "scope".  Scope is determined by your Application Permissions defined in you application that you registered at apps.dev.microsoft.com.

Third, when you receive your callback you will not have a "code" to use to go and retrieve your Access and Refresh tokens.  Instead, you will receive a "tenant" property and an "admin_consent" property.  "admin_consent" will tell you whether you have the rights or not.

Fourth, when requesting your access token, you will not supply the "scope" or "code" parameters, but you will provide a "resource" parameter, with the value "https://graph.microsoft.com".

Lastly, the URL you contact to get the token will change from "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token" to "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/token", where {tenant} will be the value returned.

Please note that in the URL that "v2.0" is missing.  That isn't a typo.  If you do not remove that from the path you will get errors about an invalid or missing "scope" parameter.

Once it successfully returns your Access and Refresh token, the flow seems to follow normal delegated access.

Here are a couple of links that Microsoft gave me, with their guidance to help figure this out.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-scopes#using-the-admin-consent-endpoint

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/authorization/app_only

(Big Thanks to Jeff at Microsoft)

Comment: Is this flow supported by the https://www.npmjs.com/package/msal library?

Answer (score 0):

Latest doc is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service

I followed it and I was able to read/write other's calendar with permission `Calendars.ReadWrite`.